# SQL 2005 SSIS - check the status of a text file before processing

Tags: file, text, ssis

Creating an SSIS (SQL 2005) project, a text file is being copied to a specific directory by another process, I want to create an SSIS package that will then copy this file to another location for processing into a database. Problem...how do I check the status of this file to ensure that it has finished being copied to the directory so that I can copy it elsewhere?

Thanks,

Derek

Answer (score 1):

We usually have the first process create a flag file (and empty text file with an .flg suffix) after it finishes copying the large file. So your process checks for the presence of the flag file.

One reason why it is good to have the flg file from the organization sending the file, is that they consider it to be finished. Without it we have loaded a file that was somehow stopped before it was finished on their end and eliminated half their sales force from access to our site. This is NOT a good thing.

Another use of flag files that we do with some customers is that they put the number of records in it that the main file should have, now we can check to make sure the main file actually has that number of records or stop the process.

Comment: interesting.....problem is the file is coming from an outside source via ftp on a daily basis, sometimes multiple times per day. The FTP task if I used the FTP task instead I would assume that if the ftp task tried to download the file and the file wasn't fully uploaded then the step would fail or prevent the file from being seen by the ftp task?

Comment: We require our outside sources to send flag files. I would not make assumptions about what the ftp task will do.

Comment: the more I think about what you are saying about the flag files the more it makes sense. Will look into this ....

Comment: ok so I have a script task that checks to see if the file exists in the specified directory, if the file exist I am setting Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success. on success then execute a "Script Task, if the file does not exist what do I set Dts.TaskResult = ?? when I set it to "Failure" windows event viewer gets en entry (which I don't want as this is not a package failure) what should I set this to inorder to have the next step in the task go to another script task I created to generate a text log file that would contain today's date, and No Source Data Found?

Comment: The other options for Dts.Results are Completion and Canceled.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought :
you can try File Modified time properties.
Compare the last modified time after some interval if it is same than file ready to use.